# Mongoose: query with array of datas and return same number of result

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an csv which is having category columns there are some category names which are repeated so I've made an array with all category names like :

```
var abc = ['A','A','B','A']  //array with duplicate data
```

as in this example, A is repeating so when am query an document with that:

```
CollectionA.find({
    categoryName: abc
}, function(err, data){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
});
```

but it just returns 2 documents for `A` & `B` but I want the same number of rows as an array is of length I want output should return the same number of documents.

Comment: Get the unique one and then using `array#map` generate all the data.

Comment: can you please tell me how?

Comment: Could you explain with the sample documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply duplicate results in callback using `Array.map()`, try:

```
var abc = ['A','A','B','A']
CollectionA.find({ categoryName: abc }, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    data = abc.map(category => data.find(d => d.category_name === category));
    console.log(data);
});
```